# replace Nans with -9999 in existing netcdf file with Python

Tags: python, nan, netcdf

I have a netcdf file where one of the variables have nan's in it. I want to read the file, then replace the nans with -9999. and then save the new netcdf file's changes. So far I have this:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

f = Dataset('anen_12km_1yr_san_angelo_00Z_100m_38_small_2014.nc','r+')
f.variables['wspd_wrf_m'][:][f.variables['wspd_wrf_m'][:] == np.nan] = -9999.
f.close()
```

When I reopen this file and print out np.max or np.min of this variable I still get nan instead of -9999. What do I need to do to replace the nans in this netcdf file and rewrite a new netcdf file with the changes of the replaced nans?

Comment: Can I ask if you want -9999 to still be recognized as "missing" in the netcdf _FillValue metadata?  i.e. that software such as ncview will treat -9999 as missing in the revised file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `== np.nan` comparison. Consider this example:

```
arr = np.random.random(3)
arr[1] = np.nan
print(arr)
print(arr == np.nan)
```

This gives:

> array([ 0.88978822,         nan,  0.71066851])
>
> [False False False]

The correct way of checking for NaNs is using `np.isnan`:

```
print(np.isnan(arr))
```

Which returns:

> [False  True False]

You can use that to replace the NaNs, similar to what you are doing now:

```
arr[np.isnan(arr)] = -9999
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to doing this in python, you can also perform this in one line from the command line using CDO:

```
cdo setmissval,-9999 in.nc out.nc
```

This will change all the missing values to -9999 and also set the _FillValue metadata to -9999 in file out.nc

Comment: Yes I was replacing the nan with -9999 because that is going to be my fillvalue for missing for my netcdf file.

Comment: When the OP asks how to do task X with language Y, some people think only answers in language Y should be offered, that's why. I personally think that offering other solutions to task X can be useful, either to others who are not wedded to a particular approach (the answers are posted publicly after all), or perhaps the OP doesn't know that simple command line options exist to solve the task. Matter of opinion I suppose :-)